# pip freeze without Conda packages

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have been using Conda for a while and it has been very helpful. However, it has happened to me lately, that when I run the command

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

to pass my project to another laptop, the **requirements.txt** file is full of Conda packages, such that when I try to restore them with the command

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

it cannot find them and fails.

My question is, **is it possible to do a `pip freeze` where the pip command does not consider Conda packages**?

At the end of the day, I only use Conda to create separate Python workspaces.

Comment: Not really a solution but you can switch to virtualenv to create your virutal environments: `python -m venv ENVIRONMENT_NAME`

Comment: _At the end of the day, I only use conda to create separate python workspaces._ Why?

Comment: @AMC because I create severals environments for testing. And I only learned before Anaconda, and it work great, but only I install PIP package,

Comment: @smirandac1978 That's a bit unusual. You should consider using Conda, it's nice.

Comment: Sounds like [pipenv](https://pypi.org/project/pipenv/) would be a more appropriate environment management tool than Conda, given your preferences.

Answer (score 5):

The `conda list` command will indicate PyPI packages with a `pypi` in the `Channel` column. Hence, a quick way would be to filter on that, e.g.,

```
conda list | awk '$4 ~ /pypi/ { print $1 "==" $2 }'
```

It should be mentioned that a more idiomatic workflow for sharing environments is to use `conda env export`, which also captures (and separates) packages from PyPI. See [the Conda documentation on sharing environments](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#sharing-an-environment) for details.

Answer (score 1):

If you are pretty sure that Anaconda is not essential for this project, you can manually remove it's packages from requirements.txt.

Comment: Hi, how do I identify coda packages from txt file?

Comment: Out of your question I desided that you already identified them. If not so, it's possible remove all except for the packages you are 100% are necessary for your project. After that try to set up a clear environment by that stripped file.

Answer (score 0):

Conda packages are often defined with an @.

Here is a code to remove them:

Linux:

```
pip freeze | grep -v "@" > requirements.txt
```

Windows

```
pip freeze | findstr /v "@" > requirements.txt
```